# How to group data changes by operation with MySQL triggers

Tags: mysql, logging, triggers

I am using triggers in MySQL to log changes to the data. These changes are recorded on a row level. I can now insert an entry in my log table for each row that is changed. However, I also need to record the operation to which the changes belong.

For example, a delete operation like "DELETE * FROM table WHERE type=x" can delete multiple rows. With the trigger I can insert an entry for each deleted row into the log table, but I would like to also provide a unique identifier for the operation as a whole, so that the log table looks something like:

```
log_id  operation_id  tablename  fieldname  oldvalue  newvalue

1       1             table      id         1         null  
2       1             table      type       a         null
3       1             table      id         2         null
4       1             table      type       a         null
5       2             table      id         3         null  
6       2             table      type       b         null
7       2             table      id         4         null
8       2             table      type       b         null
```

Is there a way in MySQL to identify the higher level operation to which the row changes belong? Or is this only possible by means of application level code? In the future it would also be nice to be able to record the transaction to which an operation belongs.

Another question is if it is possible to capture the actual SQL query, besides using the query log. I don't think so myself, but maybe I am missing something. It is of course possible to capture these at the application level, but the goal is to keep intrusions to the application level code as minimal as possible.

When this is not possible with MySQL, how is this with other database systems? For the current project it is not an option to use something other than MySQL, but it would be nice to know for future projects.

**EDIT**
In pseudo code I would like to achieve the following sort of trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tablename_log_insert
AFTER INSERT ON tablename
INSERT INTO log_operations (operation_type, relation) VALUES ('insert', 'tablename');
SET @operation_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO log_tablename(@operation_id, ...) VALUES (@operation_id, ...);
END;
```

I know this is not correct for MySQL, but maybe this pseudocode helps to clarify my question.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the query log?

Comment: I need to assign the operation ids in the triggers on a live database, I don't want to use the log afterwards.

Comment: You can log to a (live) table... see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/log-destinations.html

Comment: I did not know that. I'll go look into that right now. Thx for the link!

Comment: No problem.  If it solves your problem, I'll upgrade it to an answer.  At worst, you can probably combine it with your trigger-based approach to get to what you ultimately want.

Comment: I think I will be able to combine this with my trigger-based approach, but I will try to implement this tomorrow. If it succeeds I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the MySQL [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/query-log.html), which enables you to capture the exact statements that have been executed.  You can [choose](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/log-destinations.html) whether it's written to a file or a table.

Comment: I have a working implementation, so thanks for your help. I will award the bounty as soon as I am allowed to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the creation of a trigger, you know what some of the context: delete,insert,update.

```
CREATE TRIGGER  <name_of_trigger>  
   [BEFORE | AFTER] 
   [UPDATE | INSERT | DELETE] -- Dictates context for trigger 'action'.
ON <table_name>
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  <SQL to execute>
END
```

If you add an 'action' column to your log, you can then tell what action was used to cause a record to be inserted into the 'change' log.

Example:

```
DELIMITER $$

-- Create Update,Insert,Delete triggers that logs the result of a table update to a log  
CREATE TRIGGER  trg_AFT_INS_table  AFTER UPDATE ON table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table_log ( a, b, c, d, action)
  VALUES ( NEW.a, NEW.b, NEW.c, NEW.d, "update");
END $$
CREATE TRIGGER  trg_AFT_INS_table  AFTER INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table_log ( a, b, c, d, action)
  VALUES ( NEW.a, NEW.b, NEW.c, NEW.d, "insert");
END $$
CREATE TRIGGER  trg_AFT_INS_table  AFTER DELETE ON table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table_log ( a, b, c, d, action)
  VALUES ( OLD.a, OLD.b, OLD.c, OLD.d, "delete");
END $$
```

You could get into discussion of the BEFORE vs AFTER when logging table modifications... We found that using the 'after' values makes the log effectively the same as a 'binary log' and can be used to reconstruct, inclusive of the last modification, the table on which the logging is for.

-- J Jorgenson --